# Как задать несколько значений для ключа в .clang-tidy

Tags: c++, clang

`.clang-tidy` файл:

```
CheckOptions:
  - key:   readability-identifier-naming.MacroDefinitionCase
    value: 'UPPER_CASE, lower_case' # ошибка

CheckOptions:
  - key:   readability-identifier-naming.MacroDefinitionCase
    value: 'UPPER_CASE', 'lower_case' # ошибка
```

Если определить 2 раза, то он видит только один из них:

```
CheckOptions:
  - key:   readability-identifier-naming.MacroDefinitionCase
    value: 'UPPER_CASE'
  - key:   readability-identifier-naming.MacroDefinitionCase
    value: 'lower_case'
```

Answer (score 0):

clang-tidy поддерживает yaml и JSON форматы конфигурационных файлов. В вашем случае, это yaml, согласно синтаксису которого:

```yaml
value:
 - 'UPPER_CASE'
 - 'lower_case'
```

или

```yaml
value: ['UPPER_CASE', 'lower_case']
```

Другое дело, что [примет ли парсер значение в виде списка](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability/identifier-naming.html)? Похоже, что вам лучше использовать regex. Посмотрите похожий вопрос:

- [clang-tidy readability-identifier-naming IgnoredRegexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67165339/clang-tidy-readability-identifier-naming-ignoredregexp)